# Copied ipynb opens in read-only mode within docker container

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I'm running Docker Desktop on Windows 10. I used the repository for the [Fonduer Tutorials](https://github.com/HazyResearch/fonduer-tutorials)  to create an image to run with docker. This works fine so far and I am able to run the notebooks which are included in the repository.

I now would like to copy some jupyter notebooks and other data from the host to the container called `fonduer-tutorials-jupyter-1` to be able to make use of the fonduer framework.

I am able to copy the files to the container and also to open the jupyter notebooks, but they unfortunately do open in read-only mode.

**How can I copy files from host to container and still have permission to write on a windows machine?**

I read a lot about options like `chown` and other flags to use with COPY, but it seems like they're not available on windows machines.

Let's assume my UID received with `id -u` is 1000 and my GID received with `id -g` is 2000 if that is relevant to a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent copying the files manually and avoid the linked access restrictions described above a better solution is to map the host directory to a volume within the container via .yml-File, in this case the `docker-compose.yml`. To do so, the following needs to be added to the .yml-File.

```
volumes:
- [path to host directory]:[container path where the files should be placed in]
```

With this the files will be available both, within the container as well as on host.